# Margin between body and html

Tags: html, frontend, margin

I checked the whole page, but couldn't find the answer. There is a margin between my html tag and body tag, but I can't figure out why.
Thanks for all the answers. The site is at http://tudengid.ee/

Comment: Natural margin, just set margin to 0 for html and body

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have these rules.

Comment: There are 2 `h1` and a `p` tag in the first section that's causing the issue. `h1` has natural margin and it looks like their content isn't showing so you get the extra margin

Answer (score 1):

There are three elements inside of `section#section_1` that are causing that little space on the top. ...

```
<h1><a href="tel:+372 9002018" class="mobileCallingNumberForcalling">9002018</a></h1>
<h1><a href="tel:+372 9002018" class="heading heading__number-desktop">9002018</a></h1>
<p><a href="#section__2" class="paragraph section__1_paragraph-reverse" id="loeLisaks">Loe lisaks </a></p>
```

I set `margin: 0` on each of these and the space went away.

I figured this out by process of elimination using the browser's developer tools.

This is a common problem when using Bootstrap. Sometimes it's hard to determine where margins / spaces are set, but very [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) selectors should correct it.

The following should work, but it would also affect any other `H1` or `P` you insert into that area ...

```
#section__1 > h1,
#section__1 > p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you really needed to, you could get even more specific with [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors.

Comment: Hey! I tried it myself, but it doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: It still works. I'm sure you're running into a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem. Looking at your page, I see that all `H1` elements have `margin-bottom: .5rem` originating from Bootstrap and all `P` elements have a `margin-bottom: 1rem`, also from Bootstrap. In order to override these, you need to use a more specific selector. I'll update my answer with a recommendation, but I don't have any way to test it on your live site.

Answer (score 0):

Add following into your css:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

if above does not work, try below.
(It will override any other margin value.):

```
body {
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already had this css rule and it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's really not about margin it seems.

Comment: Please post your CSS file(s) and Javascript also if being used.

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code would help. I wanted to suggest the same that it's either a HTML or the BODY which has a margin or padding, but no.

You have this:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-section-1-1">
                    <aside>
                        <h2 class="heading section__1__heading-big">Kõik olümpiavõitjad
                            on kusagilt alustanud!</h2>
                        <p class="paragraph section__1__paragraph-intro">Kutsume Sind toetama tulevaste võitjate arengut, et
                            saaksid olla osaline nende suurtest saavutusest. Kogutud
                            toetussummat kasutame sihipäraselt sportlaste arengu
                            toetamiseks läbi  stipendiumite ja koolituste.
                        </p>
                        <button class="button button__kristian active"><p>Kristian Ilves</p></button>
                        <button class="button button__mattias"><p>Mattias Kuusik</p></button>
                        <button id="modalBtn">
                            <img src="images/Play.svg" alt="vaata videot">

                        </button>
                        <span class="button">Vaata videot</span>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/leiaendasv%C3%B5itja/" target="_blank">
                            <p class="paragraph section__1__paragraph-hashtag">#leiaendasvõitja</p>
                        </a>
                    </aside>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 displayNonePhone">
                    <p class="paragraph section__1__paragraph-secondside">TÄISVERSIOON LEHEST ON ARENDAMISEL</p>
                    <a href="http://www.nooredolumpiale.ee/toeta" target="_blank">
                        <p class="paragraph section__1__paragraph-secondsidetwo">Külasta vana lehte</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The row class has a right margin of -15 remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
section#section__1 > * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This code removed the space from top and right. 
You have set the children fixed but their the parents already has some margins.

Comment: This will also change the margins on the Bootstrap `.row` element he's using which isn't affecting the space at the top of the page.

Comment: Well "between my html tag and my body tag" was what he asked about. There's not actually a margin between those two tags, but since `<html>` and `<body>` are at the top of the page it's reasonable to assume the space at the top is the one that was causing the problem. The margins on the `.row` class are intentionally set by Bootstrap and, although Bootstrap does cause irritating CSS problems, this issue is unrelated to the one the original poster asked about.

Comment: He's using a `.row` without a `.container` wrapped around it. According to the commentary at GitHub, the horizontal scrollbar is expected behavior... A *feature* from a certain perspective. The way to fix that space at the side is to wrap a `.container` around the row. I guess they would say he's using Bootstrap wrong... https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8959#issuecomment-32554711

Comment: Then that's my bad. But I answered keeping both sides in mind. he didn't use any Bootstrap class or style that has right padding of 15px.